# Not capable of accessing a zabbix pdf generator

Tags: pdf-generation, zabbix, zabbix-custom-reports

I recently started using Zabbix as a monitoring tool and I want to generate PDF report using this [tutorial](https://tutorialesit.com/configurar-zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report-en-linux/). After following all the steps and accessing my plugin as mentioned in the tutorial using this URL http://127.0.0.1:8080/zabbix/zabbix-pdf-report/ i get 404 Not Found
I'm using Zabbix server 5.2.6 and php 7.4

If anyone is familiar with this plugin please help me.

Comment: that's because you installed in another path. Try http://127.0.0.1:8080/

Comment: @IronBishop which path ?